# problem with - ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with this script in firefox 4. I test the same script in chrome and it works, but in FF the load never stops, maybe some problem with the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var somevar = 'some info';
        var someothervar = 'some other info';
        var data = "var1=somevar&var2=someothervar";

        $.post("chart.php", data, function(theResponse){
            if (theResponse == 'sim') {
                document.write("test");
            }
            else {
                document.write("testone");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

php file have a simple `echo "sim";`

thanks

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is in the `document.write`, which can have some odd and unexpected behaviors.  Try replacing it with an `alert` for testing purposes.

Comment: Please clarify what "the load never stops" means? Also, why are you using document.write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really can't get away with using "document.write()" for such testing.  Change your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var somevar = 'some info';
    var someothervar = 'some other info';
    var data = "var1=somevar&var2=someothervar";

    $.post("chart.php", data, function(theResponse){
        if (theResponse == 'sim') {
            alert("test");
        }
        else {
            alert("testone");
        }
    });
});
```

Because the response to the request is very likely to be received *after* the browser has finished with the original page, the call to "document.write()" will have the effect of obliterating that page.

Beyond that, you can try the [TamperData plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) (if it's been updated for FF4 ...) to watch the progress of HTTP requests. FireBug will show you XHR requests too.